How to enable "complete message history" in Tomcat
I'm troubleshooting a 3rd-party app hosted in Tomcat, and I want to get as much info into the logs as possible, to debug a fault where an incoming request I expect to be forwarded is being sunk somehow and not being forwarded as expected.
I have set the log level to FINE, and am seeing an error message like the below in tomcat9-stdout.[date].log. Is there a way to update the tomcat configuration to enable complete message history? Is this even a good way to approach resolving the issue?
localhost_access_log.[date].txt
  142.75.24.52 - - [15/May/2024:11:40:07 +1200] "DELETE [url removed] HTTP/1.1" 500 -

tomcat9-stdout.[date].log
2024-05-15 11:40:07:957 +1200 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-7] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-[id removed] on ExchangeId: ID-[id removed]). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[null]

Message History (complete message history is disabled)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [from[servlet:/?httpBinding=awgCamelHttpBinding&matchOnUriPrefix=true]         ] [        20]
    ...
[route1            ] [to1               ] [http://0.0.0.0:0000/?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=true&urlRewri] [         0]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

